# Реализация native методов

Tags: java, c++, winapi, jni

Нужно с помощью *JNI* из *Java* реализовать работу с фунциями *Win32 API*:
`VirtualAlloc`, `VirtualFree`, `VirtualLock`, `VirtualUnlock`. Создал `.h` файл с помощью *javah*, но не знаю как реализовать эти методы. Нигде не могу найти пример.

Comment: Скачате **JDK**, там есть и папка Demo и Sources и полный фарш.

Comment: Похоже пользователь задавший вопрос уже 3 месяца не заходил на сайт. Он не может закрыть вопрос и не видел ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Создай java класс например WinWork. И в нём объяви нужные функции(Например VirtualAlloc, VirtualFree) и напиши загрузку либы:

```
package my.pack;

public class WinWork
{
    static
    {
       System.loadLibrary("libname");
    }

    native public static void virtualAlloc();
    native public static void virtualFree();
}
```

теперь при вызове WinWork.virtualAlloc() JVM будет искать в либах метод `Java_my_pack_WinWork_virtualAlloc(...)`
Далее нужно объявить JNI функций в C++. Нам надо создать хедеры с объявлениями функций C++, которые мы хотим вызывать.

Можно написать их вручную или заюзать:

```
javac -d bin/ src/my/pack/WinWork.java
cd bin
javah my.pack.WinWork
```

Появится примерно такой хейдер(или можно написать его вручную):

```
#include <jni.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_pack_WinWork_virtualAlloc(JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

JNIEnv — это интерфейс к виртуальной машине. Все операции с JVM выполняются с помощью него.
jclass — это идентификатор java класса, у которого есть метод native, отождествленный с этой функцией, то есть в нашем случае это WinWork. Но jclass в качестве второго параметра передается тогда, когда метод объявлен как static. Если бы он был обычным методом, то нам бы передавался jobject, который бы идентифицировал объект, метод которого мы вызвали (фактически это аналог this).

**Остается только реализовать эти функции.**

Comment: все верно написано